# Get random image from `imgur.com/random` after it redirects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

http://jsfiddle.net/ninmonkey/T2w4E/10/

I'm trying to show an image, like: `<img class="randImage" src="http://imgur.com/random" />` But it doesn't work. If you go to http://imgur.com/random , it will redirect to a valid image url.

I attempted to do the request in javascript, using the result as my new `src`. It doesn't work. (All google results are about creating a redirect. I instead need the result of the existing redirect.)

As a test I manually created a random array, and that works.

```
var names = ["http://i.imgur.com/vvIbzVL.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/0bbqCk6.gif", "http://i.imgur.com/U1AyHde.gif", "http://i.imgur.com/iUABgnE.gif", "http://i.imgur.com/mIUH5Gg.gif"];
var urlRandom = "http://imgur.com/random";

// random image from array
function randomize() {
    var item = names[Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)];
    $(".randImg").attr("src", item);       
}

//didn't work, using "http://imgur.com/random
function randomImgur() {
  $.ajax( {
    url: urlRandom, context: document.window 
  }).done(function() {
      console.log("done");
      $(".randImg").attr("src", $(this).src);

      var randImage = new Image();
      randImage.src = $(this).url;

      $(".randImg").attr("src", randImage.src);
      console.log("src = " + randImage.src );
  });

}

// toggle these to test.
//$('.randImg').click( randomize );
$('.randImg').click( randomImgur );
randomize();
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/random does not return a valid image url, it returns a random imgur gallery.

Comment: If I map the url it works. `http://imgur.com/gallery/RUJpI` to `http://i.imgur.com/RUJpI.jpg` (Regardless whether it's a png, gif, or jpg. that url will load it.) It prints out 'null' if I try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ninmonkey/hZz37/

Comment: `imgur.com/random` uses a redirect to bring you to a random gallery/picture.  Because of this, you will not be able to link to it as an image.